# Android Studio aar module loads lint.jar only on IDE Start or Module import

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint, aar

When using Android SDK with the gradle build system, one can include an `android.aar` file as a sub-project.
Within the aar, one can supply a lint.jar that implements custom lint checks ([Source](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)).

When executing `gradlew build` within the project root on the command-line, my `library.aar` is exploded and the `lint.jar` within is used for the lint checks. Even when I update the `lint.jar` within the `library.aar`, it is updated in the lint cache and the new `lint.jar` is used for the checks when I call `gradlew build` again.

If I build the same project with the same gradle command from within Android Studio 1.5, the `library.aar` is only exploded once on Module Import or on the IDE Startup.

The `lint.jar` is never updated when I update the `library.aar` in my sub-project and the old `lint.jar` from the IDE startup is still in use.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Currently I work around it by executing the gradle commands on the command-line, but it would be nice if Android Studio would work in these cases too.